# Stylus variable for the css font attribute

Tags: css, stylus

What is wrong with this variable in stylus, which sets the font attribute in the shorthand syntax?

```
button-font = 100 16px Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
```

It produces this error:

> expected "indent", got "eos"

Used here at the bottom of this code block:

```
@require "global_constants"

button.multiselect 
    height 64px
    border 1px solid brand-colour
    border-radius button-border-radius

ul.multiselect-container 
    width 100%

span.multiselect-selected-text
    color brand-colour
    text-transform uppercase
    font button-font
```

How do I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a single quote at the end of `Helvetica Neue'`:

Should it be `"Helvetica Neue"`?

Comment: Precisely. Will mark as correct when it lets me. Thanks.